# How do I install the bitarray package onto Python in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: python, visual-studio, installation, package, bitarray

I followed the instructions here: [Step 5: Install packages in your Python environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-05-installing-packages?view=vs-2019)

and that seemed to work, but I get this error when I run it:
[image]

Comment: You did not follow the docs of `bitarray`, more exactly you did get the import right.

Comment: Based on your comment, I reviewed https://pypi.org/project/bitarray/ and found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing
import bitarray
to
from bitarray import bitarray

resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Do not forget to accept your answer, this will be helpful for other members who meet the same/similar issue. Thanks for sharing the solution.